# Pandas equivalent of numpy.array2string

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas and NumPy have a lot of ways to configure array and dataframe string conversion. These are mostly global options, set with [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) and [`pandas.set_option`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html).

NumPy also provides [`numpy.array2string`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html) to perform a single array stringification operation with detailed configuration for that specific operation. This avoids messing with global options that other parts of a program may be relying on.

The closest thing I've found in Pandas is [`pandas.option_context`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html), which temporarily modifies global options and restores them afterward. (NumPy has the similar [`numpy.printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html#numpy.printoptions) context manager.) However, this still modifies global options, making it unsuitable for concurrent code, or library code that might be used in a concurrent program.

Is there any call to stringify a dataframe with custom display options, without even temporarily modifying global settings?

Answer (score 2):

[`pandas.DataFrame.to_string()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) has many of the options [`numpy.array2string()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html) offers.

[`pandas.Series.to_string()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_string.html) is the analogous routine for Series objects.

Comment: Just found the same method, after searching more. It wasn't linked from the `set_option` docs, so it was harder to find than `array2string`.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support the same options as `set_option`, though - `set_option` has a ton of stringification-related options that `DataFrame.to_string` has no equivalent for. That's a bummer. `numpy.array2string` supports almost everything `numpy.set_printoptions` supports, except the `nanstr` and `infstr` options for some reason.